# BASH string behavior oddity

Tags: string, bash

Why is branch being set to 'm' rather than 'master' in this example?

```
$ branch="[master]"
$ echo $branch
m
```

This happens from any directory I am in, but only on my mac and not on one of my linux boxes.

Comment: I can not reproduce this behavior. Please provide more info on the bash version, OS etc

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [file name expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect2), do you have a file in the current directory called `m`?

Comment: @ScottFrazer: Compare with `echo *` or `touch a b c; echo [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]` - It lists files which match the expression. If you want to avoid expansion, [Use More Quotes](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some kind of escaping issue, have you tried to escape the [ and ]?

Edit: I can reproduce the behaviour on my system, but only if a file named `m` exists:

```
[sf@zeus:~] touch m
[sf@zeus:~] branch="[master]"
[sf@zeus:~] echo $branch
m
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, just like unwind says, this has to do with file name expansion.

```
[15:33] ~$ branch="[master]"
[15:33] ~$ echo $branch 
[master]
[15:33] ~$ touch m
[15:33] ~$ echo $branch
m
[15:33] ~$
```

There must be a file or directory in your current directory named `m`.

A possible remedy for this is to use quoting:

```
$ ls m # `m' exists
m
$ echo "$branch" # yet this echoes "[master]"
[master]
```